# Rails Routing: how to separate a token from surrounding static segments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm having one of those bizarre "this used to work and then it stopped working" issues.

In my routes file I have

```
    controller :questions do
        match 'q/:topic-questions/:tag' => :search
    end
```

So a URL of format `q/java-questions/performance` would route to the `search` action with `params[:topic] = java` and `params[:tag] = performance`

This used to work, but now I get a route not found error.  If I switch to

```
match 'q/(:topic)-questions/:tag' => :search
```

it finds the route again, but I don't want `topic` to be an optional parameter.  I think this implies that it's having trouble separating out `:topic-questions` into a token and then a static string.  If there another way to neatly separate out the token, other then putting it in `()`?

Note - the reason why topic cannot be an optional parameter, is that optional parameters are not included in the cache keys when doing action caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your caching issues, just make the "-questions" part optional:

```
controller :questions do
    match 'q/:topic(-questions)/:tag' => :search
end
```

this will match `q/java-questions/performance` and `q/java/performance` the cache key is always distinct to the topic "java"

Edit:

This is a modification of @sorens post (he did 99% of the work):

```
controller :questions do
    match 'q/:topic-:modifier/:tag' => :search, :defaults => {:modifier => 'questions'}, :as => :question_topic_tag
end
```

now your helper looks like:

`question_topic_tag_path('java', 'performance')` gives you `q/java-questions/performance`

Comment: Oh, this one really gave me hope.  But alas, when routes are generated it then generates `q/java/performance` instead of `q/java-questions/performance`.

Answer (score 3):

what about:

```
controller :questions do
    match 'q/:topic-:modifier/:tag' => :search
end
```

then you would have three parameters

```
params[:topic]
params[:modifier]
params[:tag]
```

and you could then ignore the `params[:modifier]` one.

Comment: of course, now that i see it in print, i wonder if /:a-:b/ is possible in a route...

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with Dave Newton about trying to re-factor your URL structure, but you could possibly allow the "-questions" through the route and chop it off from params[:topic] in your controller and use constraints to validate the presence of something before "-questions" in the URL

```
controller :posts do
  match 'q/:topic/:tag' => :index, :topic => /.+-questions/
end
```

Then in your controller you would need something like

```
topic = params[:topic].gsub!(/-questions/, "")
```

This smells a bit ;)

Comment: Mmm, stinky, but interesting, so +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a regex condition that forces it to non-empty.

```
match 'q/(:topic)-questions/:tag' => :search, :topic => /[A-Za-z]*/ # Or whatever.
```

See the [Segment Constraints](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) section of the routing docs for details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, the reason that I don't want ti to be optional is due to action caching.  I've noticed that if a parameter is optional it isn't included in the cache key.  So, if topic is optional, then I wind up with idential cache keys for /q/java-questions/performance and /q/php-questions/performance.

Comment: @cailinanne Hmm, not sure then, although you could create a non-ambiguous route and redirect/render the real one via an engine, normal server rewriting methods (depends on server), or inside Rails itself. Or standardize on a different URL format that's perhaps a bit more RESTful, like q/:topic/questions/:tag.

Comment: why don't you make the (-questions) optional then?

Answer (score 0):

```
match 'q/:topic:fix_it/:tag' => :search, :fix_it => /-questions/
```